# How to make context with timeout and retries in Go?

Tags: go

I try to make context with timeout && several retries in Go.
Here is the code example

```
func readRetry(port io.ReadWriteCloser, timeout, cnt int) []byte {
    fmt.Println("IN READ RETRY")
    for i := 0; i < cnt; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Read attempt:", i)
        res := readWithContext(timeout, port)
        if res != nil {
            return res
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func readWithContext(timeout int, port io.ReadWriteCloser) []byte {
    fmt.Println("IN readWithContext")
    fmt.Println("Opening channel")
    rcvCh := make(chan []byte)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(time.Second*time.Duration(timeout)))
    defer cancel()

    go reader(ctx, port, rcvCh)

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("reader: context cancelled")
            return nil
        case buf := <-rcvCh:
            fmt.Println("reader: got data")
            return buf
        }
    }
}

func reader(ctx context.Context, port io.ReadWriteCloser, rcvCh chan []byte) {

    fmt.Println("IN reader")

    answ := make([]byte, 1024)
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    var err error

    for {
        i := 0
        i, err = port.Read(answ)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            log.Printf("port.Read: %v", err)
        }
        if i != 0 {
            answ = answ[:i]
            buf.Write(answ)
            if buf.Bytes()[len(buf.Bytes())-1] == delimiter {
                fmt.Print("Received: ")
                printBuf(buf.Bytes())
                rcvCh <- buf.Bytes() //if there is no data in the first attempt, cannot write to the channel here!!
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I call **readRetry** result := readRetry(port, 2, 5) // 2 seconds timeout, 5 retries. But if data is not ready for the first time, then **reader** cannot write to **rcvCh** . It might be full? Why? If I try to close channel at the end of **readWithContext** execution, there is a collision - write to closed channel. Where is the collision? It think, **readWithContext** starts every time as a new instance, creates a new instance of **rcvCh**, and if the **reader** closes via timeout, all chain of functions with their local variables, including the channel, has been destroyed. But, it seems, I make a mistake. So, how to make retries?
Look, how the log looks like:

```
IN READ RETRY
Read attempt: 1
IN readWithContext
Opening channel
IN reader
Start reader
Received: 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0d //<- data is received, but not written to the channel!!
reader: context cancelled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every retry creates a new reader and a new channel. If `readWithContext` times out, the reader is still there waiting, and probably eventually reading, but now there's nobody listening on the other end of the channel, so that reader is leaked.

Have a single `reader` goroutine, and a single channel, use `readWithContext` to read from it. If the context expires and all retries are exhausted, you have to stop the reader as well.

Comment: Can anybody help how to prevent reader function leak? How to redesign code to kill reader by context cancellation together with readWithContext ? Thanks.